# AsyncTask cannot show Toast message when called from inside OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, toast, onitemclicklistener

I want to show a Toast message "Processing.. Please wait." while doing some processing after the user presses on a listview item. AsyncTask doesn't works when called from lv.setOnItemClickListener (but works when called from button.setOnClickListener).

Any idea why?

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private static Context context;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        context = this;

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

        // this DOESN't show the waiting message while processing
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
                new AsyncMsg(position).execute();
            }
        });

        // this shows the waiting message while processing 
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = 0; //first item
                new AsyncMsg(position).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showWaitMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Processing.. Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();
    }
}
```

AsyncTask: AsyncMsg.java

```
public class AsyncMsg extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public int position;

    public AsyncMsg(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        MyActivity.showWaitMessage();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // do some long process with position
    }

    public void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```

Comment: you can pass context and display toast in asynctask

Comment: Thanks. I tried it now but it doesn't help in showing the message when the listview item is pressed.

Comment: it will but why do you need a toast. you could display a progress dialog.

Comment: The toast is enough for waiting no more than one second, and there is no progress information to show (i.e. not like downloading). My question is why does it work on button click but NOT on listview item click?

Answer (score 1):

why dont you try this

```
public class AsyncMsg extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public int position;
    Context context;
    public AsyncMsg(int position,Context con) {
        this.position = position;
        context =con;
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Processing.. Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
           .show();
    }
   }
```

and then call like this

```
 new AsyncMsg(position,context).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use as context `MyActivity.this` in the Toast.make(..).

Comment: Its a static method, you cant access instance from it